# Java string not converted to lower case

Tags: java, string

Why does the string `s` print `"Hello, World"` after converting to lower case?

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Hello, World";
        s.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String`s are immutable. You need to re assign the result of `String#toLowerCase` to the variable:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are special kind of objects in Java. Java developers deliberately created them to be **immutable** (for various security and performance reasons).

That means that when you think you change the state of a String object, actually a new String object is created (and the previous is not really changed).

Therefore, to make your code work, you have to assign the result of the method to some string:

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: *when you change the state of a String object* this wording is wrong. Since it's immutable, you cannot change its state. Any operation that involves changing the state of the object will create a new object with the new state, and the state of the *older* object will remain intact.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I was thinking about it while I wrote it (whether it would be confusing). And it sure was, it seems. Fixed it, thanks!